# Theme resets back to system after app is restarted

Tags: java, android

This is the code that I use to switch between themes (**Light**, **Dark** and **Set by System**). I have radio buttons when clicked call this function:

```java
public void setAppearance(View view) {
    int selected = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

    if (selected == 0) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("appearance", "light").apply();
    } else if (selected == 1) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putString("appearance", "dark").apply();
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
        sharedPreferences.edit().remove("appearance").apply();
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly. However, once I restart the app, it goes back to following the system theme.

I tried adding this before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` of the *Home Activity*:

```java
String theme = sharedPreferences.getString("appearance", "system");

if (theme.equals("light")) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
} else if (theme.equals("dark")) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
} else {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
}
```

This seems to do the job, but I notice the *Home Activity* is launched twice (also takes a longer time to load), when I click the back button, it shows another *Home Activity*.

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode();` works during the apps runtime. So it has to be set again whenever you re-launch it by saving the selected theme in `SharedPreferences`. So the issue I was facing was the dual launch of my activity. After some experimenting I found that it worked when I placed the code before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` too (Not just `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);`).

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String theme = sharedPreferences.getString("appearance", "system");

    if (theme.equals("light")) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    } else if (theme.equals("dark")) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
```

Comment: While testing on Android 7 and above I found that I now had to add `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode()` in `Application` `onCreate` method too. Just putting it to `onCreate` of activity doesn't fully update all the theme colors after the app restart.